# How to print JSON objects with inner key value objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following structure of JSON objects. Each `Mealplan` consists of a `key` and a `value` which is an object `meal`.

```
id: 1,
mealsPerWeek: {
    Monday: {
       id: 4,
       name: "Burger",
    },
    Tuesday: {
       id: 3,
       name: "Salad",
    },
id: 2,
mealsPerWeek: {
    Monday: {
       id: 3,
       name: "Salad",
    },
    Tuesday: {
       id: 2,
       name: "Fishburger",
    },
```

And I want to create a list like this (as innerHTML):

```
ID: 1

 - Monday: Burger 
 - Tuesday: Salad

ID 2: 

 - Monday: Salad 
 - Tuesday: Fishburger
```

I already created a loop, to get the `mealplan` ID's. The assets are coming through an XmlHttpRequest:

```
renderMealplan(assets) {
    let mealplan = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
        mealplan[i] = {
            id: assets[i].id,
            mealsPerWeek: assets[i].mealsPerWeek,
        }
    }
 }
```

I already tried getting getting a list of the `meal` names like this:

```
 let content = ''
        mealplan.forEach(mealplan => {
            content += '<h1>' + mealplan.id + '</h1>' + '<ul>' +
                '<li>' + JSON.stringify(mealplan.mealsPerWeek.Monday) +'</li>' +
        }); + '</ul>'
```

but the outcome is just:

```
1
{"id":4,"name":"Burger"}
```

Using `JSON.stringify(mealplan.mealsPerWeek.Monday.name` also does not print the name of the meal because it is undefined.

How do I get all the information seperated and print it in a list? Also I don't find the solution to extract the `keys` of mealsPerWeek.

Comment: can you put your whole json object, the one you posted makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input data did not seem to be syntactically correct. Below I tried to put it into some valid form:

```js
const arr=[
{id: 1,
 mealsPerWeek: { Monday: {id: 4,name: "Burger"},
                Tuesday: {id: 3,name: "Salad" }}},
{id: 2,
 mealsPerWeek: { Monday: {id: 3,name: "Salad",},
                Tuesday: {id: 2,name: "Fishburger"}}}];
                
 document.getElementById('cont').innerHTML=arr.map(h=>
  `<h1>ID: ${h.id}</h1><ul>`
  +Object.entries(h.mealsPerWeek).map(([day,{name}])=>
  `<li>${day}: ${name}</li>`).join('\n')+'</ul>').join('\n')
```

```html
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Let me know if this is of any value to you?

A few explanations:

- You don't need to apply `JSON.stringfy()` on an object's property if you want to get its value. `arr[0].mealsPerWeek.Monday.name` should directly get you the value "Burger".
- `Object.entries(obj)` will return an array of arrays. Each sub-array will contain the key and value for each property of object `obj`
- I used ES6 destructuring in the argument list for map: `.map(([day,{name}])=>...`. This way I have direct access to the key as `day`and the meal name in the value-object as `name`.

Answer (score 0):

For extracting the keys of mealsPerWeek:
You simply add the following line:

```
this.mealPlans.forEach((mealPlan)={
 mealPlan.meals = Object.keys(mealPlan.mealsPerWeek)
})
```

And than you can add the following for your content:

```
 let content = ''
    essensplan.forEach(mealplan => {
        content += '<h1>' + mealplan.id + '</h1>' + '<ul>' +
            '<li>' + JSON.stringify(mealplan.mealsPerWeek[mealPlan.meals[0]]) +'</li>' +
    }); + '</ul>'
```

Further you already know how to add the for loop for `mealPlan.meals` too.